# initialisation of const member of base class into derive class

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
public:
    const int x;
    base():x(5){}

};

class der : public base {
public:
    der():x(10){}
};

der d;
```

My aim is when instance of base class is created it will initialise x as 5 and when instance of der class is created it will initialise x as 10. But compiler is giving error.
As x is inherited from class base, why is it giving error?

Comment: i am not changing, i am only assigning it into derive class

Comment: @trojanfoe: because a Derived class cannot initialize a Base attribute in its initializer list.

Comment: The correct fix in C++ for problems with `const` is almost never to just ignore them by removing `const` until they go away. But this isn't a problem with `const`, it's a problem with initializer lists, and merely removing `const` will not make it go away. That said, there's an issue with non-static `const` data members of classes, that you'll find the class cannot be assigned in the default way. So you can't write `base a; base b; a = b;`, because the synthesized assignment operator can't do `a.x = b.x;`. So you'd have to implement your own assignment operator if you want to write `a = b`.

Comment: @SteveJessop If x is part of the state of the object, and x is constant, then meaningful assignment is impossible anyway. IMO a `public const` data member that is part of the object state may be legitimate design choice, but you have to be consistent and not pretend you can do assignment when you can't. OTOH, the constant data member may be part of the identity and not part of the value of the object. It isn't clear from the example.

Comment: "i am not changing, i am only assigning it into derive class" Assignment is a change, you certainly mean "I am **initialising** it from the derived class". But the variable has already been initialised, and **initialisation** implies **only once**.

Comment: "meaningful assignment is impossible anyway" - it's certainly very ugly. With `a = b` it sort of makes sense that you could copy the rest of the state, but for example `base b; derived d; b = d;` is probably meaningless.

Comment: It is natural to assume that `a = b;` has the postcondition `a == b`. `operator==` should test the x member for equality iff x is part of the "value" of the object. (The "value" is a mathematical abstraction defined on existing objects.) Note that this can also work with `b = d;` as `b == d` will resolve to `base == base` as the only viable candidate, so this postcondition might be satisfied even in case of slicing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't initialize a base class member in the initializer list for a constructor in the derived class. The initializer list can contain bases, and members in this class, but not members in bases.

Admittedly, the standardese for this isn't entirely clear. 12.6.2/2 of C++03:

> Unless the mem-initializer-id names a nonstatic data member of the
>   constructor’s class or a direct or virtual base of that class, the
>   mem-initializer is ill-formed.

It means "(a nonstatic data member of the constructor's class) or (a direct or virtual base)". It doesn't mean "a nonstatic data member of (the constructor's class or a direct or virtual base)". The sentence is ambiguous, but if you took the second reading then you couldn't put bases in the initializer-list at all, and the very next sentence in the standard makes it clear that you can.

As for why it's not allowed, that's a standard rationale question and I'm guessing at the motives of the authors of the standard. But basically because it's the base class's responsibility to initialize its own members, not the derived class's responsibility.

Probably you should add an `int` constructor to `base`.

Comment: If it was allowed, the member would be initialised twice, _unless_ you introduce the concept that a derived ctor init-list **can override** a base ctor init-list for accessible members or base classes. It would break encapsulation in the case of `base`, as it breaks the idea that a public const variable is a constant set in the ctor of the class that declares it. Compare with `virtual` base classes initialisation.

Answer (score 7):

You can make this work with a little adjustment...

```
#include <cassert>

class base
{
public:
    const int x;
    base()
        :x(5)
    {
    }

protected:
    base(const int default_x)
        :x(default_x)
    {
    }
};

class der: public base
{
public:
    der()
        :base(10)
    {
    }
};

struct der2: public base
{
    der2()
        :base()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    base b;
    assert(b.x == 5);
    der d;
    assert(d.x == 10);
    der2 d2;
    assert(d2.x == 5);
    return d.x;
}
```

This provides a constructor, accessible by derived classes, that can provide a default value with which to initialise `base.x`.

Comment: It doesn't compile if you try to declare an object of type base.

Comment: ... because the protected constructor's parameter shouldn't have a default. There's no benefit in having one, since without it the no-args constructor will be used anyway.

Comment: I was editing this while you commented and down-voted. It's fixed now.

Comment: To keep the ability to set x from a class derived from `der`, you would need another `protected` ctor in `der` that takes an int. BTW, `const` is not extremely useful in this context: `base(const int default_x)` This remark shall _not_ be taken to mean that you shall remove this `const`!

Comment: @curiousguy: `const` in the parameter list may not be extremely useful here, but it is also harmless, and could prevent future errors from appearing when the body of the constructor will change, so why not have it?

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
class base {
public:
    static const int x = 5;
};

class der : public base {
public:
    static const int x = 10;
};
```

If you want to change x depending on your constructor, you have to make it non-static.

A non-static const is the same as a non-const variable once compiled. If you want to enforce a member variable to be read-only, use non-static const. If you want to set a constant whose scope is restricted to a single class, use static const.

Comment: Why should const in classes be static?

Comment: const has to be static in classes to be truly constant.

Comment: No. It will be constant even without static. But it will be constant for the object, not for the whole class (as would a static do).

Comment: Creating a const with an object involves modifying that const during object creation. A non-static const is the same as a non-const variable (albeit read-only), and I doubt that is what he wants, as he's setting them to literals.

Comment: A non-static const is NOT the same as a non-const variable. Your example is completely different than the question. Do you know what static does? Your member x will be THE SAME for all instances of the class, whereas a non-static const can differ between instances. Even if the op's code doesn't exemplify this, it still doesn't make it ok.

Comment: A non-static const is the same as a non-const variable once compiled. If you want to enforce a member variable to be read-only, use non-static const. If you want to set a constant whose scope is restricted to a single class, use static const.

Comment: The main difference between using a static or non-static data member here is what happens when you write `der d; ((base*)&d)->x;`. If you use a static data member you get `5`, if you use a non-static data member you get `10`. So the questioner should decide which to use on the basis of what result is needed for that expression, and others like it -- should each object have its own copy of `x`, or not.

Comment: :| Once again, they are not the same. You can't change the non-static const, whereas you can change the non-const variable. Furthermore, it's the third time I'm saying that in the op's question, the constant's scope is not class-wide, but object-wide.

Comment: As I've said, they're the same once compiled, just as public and private don't do anything once compiled. You can change a non-static const through casting or a simply memcopy, and so it is not truly constant. @Steve Jessop very good point!

Comment: @Pubby8: a non-static non-const and non-static const data member are not entirely the same once compiled. The compiler is allowed to apply more optimizations to the latter, so for example if you do `base b; some_fn_with_unknown_effect(&b); std::cout << b.x;`, then if `x` is const the compiler is allowed to use a fixed value `5` for the output, whereas if `x` is non-const it has to load it from `b` after calling the function. It's UB to change the const member through casting/memcpy, hence the difference, and it may or may not "appear to work".

Comment: @Pubby8 even after compilation they are not the same. Statics reside in the static memory space reserved by the system, while members reside at a specific offset from the object's base address. The static only appears once after compilation and at runtime, the non-static (const or not) will be created with every object.

Comment: FFS guys, this could go on all day. Pubby keeps saying that a "non-static const is the same as a non-const", meaning that a non-static const is the same as a non-static non-const. This is false, but what Luchian keeps saying is that there's a difference between a non-static const and a static non-const -- true but not relevant to Pubby's claims. Sort it out :-)

Comment: :)) =)) Right, he must have edited the comments... 4th comment - "A non-static const is the same as a non-const variable" <-- that's what I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

This may be over-engineered compared the original question, but please consider:

```
template <typename T, class C, int index=0> 
// C and index just to avoid ambiguity
class constant_member {
    const T m;
    constant_member (T m_) :m(m_) {}
};

class base : virtual public constant_member<int, base> {
public:
    base () : constant_member<int, base>(5) {}
    int x () const { return constant_member<int, base>::m; }
};

class der : public base {
public:
    der () : constant_member<int, base>(10) {}
};

class der2 : public der{
public:
    der2 () {} // ill-formed: no match for 
               // constant_member<int, base>::constant_member() 
};
```

Comment: This is verbose, non-obvious (maybe impossible to understand for beginners), and it will be very inefficient to convert to `virtual` base class just to read a member variable. I am *not* really suggesting this as a real world solution.